# Retrieve value from ThingSpeak using ESP8266 with Arduino setup

Tags: esp8266

I just started learning ESP8266 and in my first project I am successfully able to send data to ThingSpeak.com using ESP8266 with following code:

```
uploadData() {
  String apiKey = "ESDS8678890SDDS";
  String myData = "45.5"; // example of data to send
  if (espClient.connect(server,80)) {
    String postStr = apiKey;
    postStr +="&field1=";
    postStr += String(myData);
    postStr += "\r\n\r\n";
    espClient.print("POST /update HTTP/1.1\n");
    espClient.print("Host: api.thingspeak.com\n");
    espClient.print("Connection: close\n");
    espClient.print("X-THINGSPEAKAPIKEY: "+apiKey+"\n");
    espClient.print("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\n");
    espClient.print("Content-Length: ");
    espClient.print(postStr.length());
    espClient.print("\n\n");
    espClient.print(postStr);
    Serial.print(postStr);
    Serial.print("My Data: ");
    Serial.print(myData);
    Serial.print("\n");
  }
  espClient.stop();
}
```

But I have no idea how to retrieve data from ThingSpeak using ESP8266.

```
// Using XXXXX here as my channel is private
GET https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/XXXXXX/fields/1.json?results=2
```

I think I have to use the above GET string to get the fields data. But I don't know how to create the request string.

Help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Connect to the server as usual with `espClient.connect()`. The following request should return a JSON object containing your channel description and the first 2 entries in your feed:

```
espClient.println("GET /channels/CHANNEL_ID/feeds.json?results=2 HTTP/1.1");
espClient.println("Host: api.thingspeak.com");
espClient.println("Connection: close");
espClient.println();
```

If it's a private channel, then you must supply your Read API key like this:

```
espClient.println("GET /channels/CHANNEL_ID/feeds.json?api_key=<your API key>&results=2 HTTP/1.1");
```

Notice that I use `println()` and not `print()` in order to implicitly terminate each request line properly. You should end each line not with `\n` but with **`\r\n`**. You only need to type this yourself if you use `print()`.

To read the returned JSON data:

```
while (espClient.available() == 0);  // wait till something comes in; you may want to add a timeout here

unsigned long lastRead = millis();  // keeps track of last time a byte was read
while (millis() - lastRead < 2000) {  // while 2 secs havent passed since a byte was read
  while (espClient.available()) {
    Serial.print(espClient.read());
    lastRead = millis();   // update last time something was read
  }
}
client.stop();  // close socket
```

To parse the JSON string, you either get a library from GitHub or you parse the string yourself.